# Retrieving app txt data! CoreData Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, xcode6

I have made a swift app that logs data into a sqlite file and it consists of 5 txt entry's and when someone enters data into them all and press's save, they will be saved into my sqlite file!

But this issue is when I want to retrieve data! I was following a tutorial on youtube on how to use coredata and save and retrieve inputed data into some text fields. But when he wrote the retrieve code, it only retreived the last known input! But I was wondering if there is anyway I could use only one of the textboxs info to then bring up all the rest of the info in all 5 text fields and Press Retrieve and it will bring it all up! Sort of like a password and then when correct it shows the data that was saved under that password!

Sorry this has been a bit long winded and before you ask, here is the code I used http://pastebin.com/BEq496tY

Thanks,
George Barlow

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the entity and storyboard!

The View Controller ->
http://i.stack.imgur.com/lYq6t.png

The Enity file -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/LN1Sa.png

Answer (score 0):

First, rename your entity from `ID` to something else, and the attribute `id` to something else. "ID" is used for so many things, you are likely to run into a problem. I will call your entity `Item` and the id `idNumber`.

Second, when saving your object, you take the stuff from the text fields and put it into the appropriate place, e.g.

```
item.txt1 = textField1.text
item.txt2 = textField2.text
// etc.
```

Similarly, when retrieving, you should populate all text fields.

```
textField1.text = item.txt1
textField2.text = item.txt2
// etc.
```

To have some kind of search functionality you would have to first find out which field is filled with data and then search for that with a predicate, like

```
NSPredicate(format: "txt1 = %@", textField1.txt)
```

To create new items you would do something like

```
let item = NSEntityDescription. insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Item",
   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext)
// configure item
self.managedObjectContext.save(nil)
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: so what would this be like in my code! Seen as i am new to swift @Mundi

Comment: And would you mind explaining how I would insert these! :D @Mundi

Comment: I updated my answer, but this is really basic stuff that you can just copy from the Apple templates or look up in the documentation. If you still need more concepts, you might want to do a tutorial or ask another question on SOF.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work! Swift finds an error where it cant locate managedObjectContext in ViewController.swift @Mundi

Comment: You should not withdraw your answer acceptance. Instead you should assign a managed object context to your view controller. Please!